# C not printing whole string

Tags: c, printing, output

My problem is that it's only printing out 1 letter, when it's supposed to print the whole string. I would really appreciate your help! Thank you once again for helping me.

```
#include < stdio.h >

int main(void) {

    int val;

    val=1;

    while (val!=0) {

        printf("\n");

        printf("Choose\n");

        printf("1) Add new letter\n");

        printf("2) Empty string\n");

        printf("3) Print string\n");

        printf("0) Stop\n");

        printf("Choice: ");

        scanf("%d",&val);

        printf("\n");

        char sign[200];

        char sign2[200];

        int size;

        size = strlen(sign2);

        switch (val) {

            case 1:

                printf("Give some letter: ");

                scanf("%s",&sign2);

                strcpy(sign, "");

                strcat(sign,sign2);

                sign2[size]=sign2;

                sign2[size+1]='\0';

                break;

            case 2:

                if (val==2) {

                    printf("Emptied string.\n");

                    sign2[0] = '\0';

                }
                break;

            case 3:

                if (size == 0) {

                    printf("Is empty\n");


                } else {

                    printf("String: %s\n",sign);

                }

                break;

            case 0:

                printf("Stopping.\n");

                break;

            default:

                printf("Unknown.\n");

                break;

        }

    }

        return 0;
}
```

My problem is that it's only printing out 1 letter, when it's supposed to print the whole string. I would really appreciate your help! Thank you once again for helping me.

Comment: `size = strlen(sign2);`?

Comment: Can be strlen(sign), doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of problem - but yes we can discuss one by one

- `strlen` returns the length of the nul terminated `char` array. The content of the array in your case is indeterminate at the time you are applying `strlen` on it. This is undefined behavior. You may wanted to initialize the char array `char sign2[200]={0}` so that you can use `strlen` on it. (By the way - if you want to get the size of the char array use `sizeof(sign2)` )
- `scanf("%s",&sign2);` will be `scanf("%s",sign2);` because `char` array converted ("decays") into pointer to the first element - which is a pointer to the `sign2[0]`. That is what you are supposed to pass to `scanf`. Your compiler complained about it.
- `sign2[size]=sign2;` is not doing what you are thinking it is doing - this is trying to assign a `char*` to a `char` variable which is wrong.
- Also every time you are overwriting what is there in `sign2`. Ideally you want to get a `char` input and that will be `scanf(" %c",&somecharvar);`.
- After you get the input in `somecharvar` then adding it would be easy. You can simply get the length of the string and then add the character and also the nul terminating `char`. In case you are thinking - what will be the case the very first time then you will have do one thing - initialized `sign2` with `\0` initially. That way even if you call `strlen` over it the very first time - it will give you the result of `0`.

  ```
  char somevar;
  if( scanf(" %c",&somevar)!= 1){
      fprintf(stderr,"Error in input\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  size_t sz = strlen(sign2);
  if(sz+1 < sizeof(sign2)){
      sign2[sz]=somevar;
      sign2[sz+1]=0;
  } else {
      fprintf(stderr,"Noe enough space\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  ```
- As you have already seen, `strlen` returns the length of the string which of type `size_t`. `size_t` is guaranteed to hold the size of any object in `C`.
- For `scanf` always check it's return value, in case it fails you will know it and terminate the program or handle it accordingly( most plausible being - eating out the wrong inputs from `stdin` that would still be there because `scanf` couldn't parse it).
- This is a good practice you can say - instead of using hard-coded value (magic numbers) like `200` or similar use a `macro` or constant to incorporate them.

Comment: Thank you! Lots to be learned from this. Was mainly looking if there was something quick I was missing that was causing it not to print the whole string.

Comment: @Jaakkath.: The thing is it didn't print other characters becasuse your logic was wrong. But now it should work.

Comment: Did you remove the whole switch/cases? Or where are these all supposed to go?

Comment: @Jaakkath.: No..just in the `case 1` where you are inserting `char` though `char sign2[200]={0}` should be where you declared `sign2`.